# Why won't my jQuery script load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm just getting started with HTML/CSS/jQuery and I tried starting basic. Currently I have a .html, .css, and .js. My index.html will load the .css but will not load the .js. Is there something wrong with my code?

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Super Mario!</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://i1061.photobucket.com/albums/t480/ericqweinstein/mario.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
img {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
        case 65:
            $('img').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
            break;
        case 83:
            $('img').animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
            break;
        case 87:
            $('img').animate({top: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
            break;
        case 68:
            $('img').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
});
```

Please help me figure out why this doesn't work. Some additional info, they're all located in the same folder on my desktop. There are no sub folders.

Comment: can you provide your directory structure?

Comment: Make sure that script.js is in same folder as index.html

Comment: Where your script file is located in your project

Comment: You mentioned $(document).ready in your code. Are you using jquery. If you using jquery you should add jquery library

Answer (score 6):

You are using jQuery code in your JavaScript file, but do not include the jquery Lib in the HTML.

Add this line (or you can substitute with another link to a hosted jQuery library) *before* loading your script (assuming you use the current jQuery version - else include the appropriate version):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

So your `<head>` should look like this:

```
<!-- some code -->
<head>
    <title>Super Mario!</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- some code -->
```

Comment: The directory structure is: C:\Users\<username>\Documents\project

Comment: @user2392794 I think your script is loaded correctly, but can't be executed, because jQuery is missing. You might look into the developer tools / error console and should see some kind of "undefined reference: $"-error message for your script.

Answer (score 1):

You're not including the jQuery library. Include this in your head:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Include this in your head` I hope you mean `in your code's head` :D

Comment: Haha, well if you remember to always add it in your code's head it's somehow stuck in your head :D

Comment: Thanks everyone. I didn't know about including the jQuery lib. For some reason... it just slipped my mind. I appreciate all the help. Thanks again everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Add **jquery** from any **CDN**

```
<head>
    <title>Super Mario!</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery script is not loading because you did not add the jQuery library before your script in the javascript file. The other answers are fine but I wanted to expand that you can use jQuery from various externally hosted libraries. And you can use any version that you require so long as it is compatible with what you are doing.

I personally use [CDNJS](http://www.cdnjs.com) which hosts a lot of useful javascript libraries. You can visit their site and find jQuery, then pick the version that you want

[image: screenshot of versions available at CDNJS]

After you pick the version that you need you will be presented with the option to copy the link, put that in your src

[image]

You can either put that in your `<head>` or before the closing `</body>`

### Example 1

```
<head>
    <!-- meta tags and CSS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

### Example 2

```
        <!-- other HTML and content -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is also very important to note that if you add any other jQuery plugin or library that it should be added after jQuery but before your custom JS file. Do not edit the files with the libraries, add another file, this can be your `custom.js`, `main.js` or whatever you want to call it.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="someplugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```